# Create a Windows Mobile 6.5.3 project in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, mobile

What do I need to install so that I can develop applications for Windows Mobile 6.5.3 devices, using Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 22):

Since it took me like 3 days of research to figure out how to actually do this I'm creating this article to hopefully ease some others pain.

Firstly, have Visual Studio 2008 installed. Secondly, install these add on pieces:

1. Windows Mobile 6 Professional and Standard Software Development Kits Refresh
   http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=06111a3a-a651-4745-88ef-3d48091a390b&displaylang=en
2. Windows Mobile 6.1.4 Professional Images (USA)
   http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=1A7A6B52-F89E-4354-84CE-5D19C204498A&displaylang=en
3. Windows Mobile 6.5 Professional Developer Tool Kit (USA)
   http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=20686a1d-97a8-4f80-bc6a-ae010e085a6e&displaylang=en
4. Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional DTK
   http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c0213f68-2e01-4e5c-a8b2-35e081dcf1ca&displaylang=en

You may not need to install all of these but I did and it won't hurt anything most likely.  nextly

1. Open Visual Studio 2008 and create a new project for **Smart Device** click ok
2. Select Device Application on the main window with the icons and change the **target platform** to **Windows Mobile 6 Standard SDK**. Click **OK**.
3. Right click on the the **Project Name** in the solution explorer and select **Change Target Platform** and choose **Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional SDK**. Click Ok.
4. The project will need to be closed and reopened.

That simple!

Comment: new links:
1 - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6135

2 - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9263

3 - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17284

4 - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5389

Comment: Can anyone please provide a mirror to Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional DTK? It appears Microsoft has taken it offline ( @RodrigodeBonaSartor 's links unfortunately do not work either).

Comment: Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional DTK can be downloaded from archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20171010221747/https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/E/2/1E2BB9F3-355B-4E0B-8487-05F4F327C1FE/Windows%20Mobile%206.5.3%20Professional%20DTK.msi

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 (and probably some earlier versions) I think Andrew's answer is missing something important.  It also includes some packages that shouldn't be needed for strictly 6.5.3 development.  For reference, if you attempt to install the 6.5.3 DTK and missing anything, it should tell you.

At a minimum, you should only need the following:

- VS 2008 Professional
- Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK Refresh https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6135
- Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional DTK https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5389
- Windows Mobile Device Center 6.1 Driver
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3182

Comment: Also for Windows 10, it is necessary to install additional tools in order to run successfully. More details in this article:  https://support.waspbarcode.com/kb/articles/windows-mobile-device-center-troubleshooting-on-windows-10